# Android: Unable to scan for BLE devices even after using setEnableBle in LocationSettingsRequest

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location, android-ble

In my app I want to search nearby users using both GPS and BLE. I came across the [`SettingsClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) which is used to enable GPS by showing a Popup in case it isn't enabled.

Interestingly, it also has a `setNeedBle` method which as per the docs

> Sets whether the client wants BLE scan to be enabled. When this flag
>   is set to true, if the platform supports BLE scan mode and Bluetooth
>   is off, the dialog will prompt the user to enable BLE scan. If the
>   platform doesn't support BLE scan mode, the dialog will prompt to
>   enable Bluetooth.

This is perfect for me. If I can scan for BLE devices when Bluetooth is off that would be amazing. I followed [this official guide](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) to setup things and I see the popup like this.

[image]

But after selecting OK when I try to do a BLE scan of nearby devices, I get this error.

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10834 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:947)
        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onScannerRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:460)
        at android.bluetooth.le.IScannerCallback$Stub.onTransact(IScannerCallback.java:57)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Apparently this indicates that I need the permission `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` which isn't available to third-party apps.

I am confused then what is even the point of having the `setNeedBle` function if only system apps can use it? Or am I missing something? Is it possible to do a BLE scan with this permission or will I have to ask users to enable the Bluetooth? Thanks!